# Update a google sheet from GitHub repository?

Tags: javascript, git, github, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every day a new CSV file is added to a GitHub repository. Is there a way to update a google sheets file with the most recent data as soon as the new file is published?

This is what I have tried so far:

in a cell in my google sheets:

```
=ImportData("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/2019-nCoV/master/daily_case_updates/02-10-2020_1030.csv")
```

This works as expected, quite perfectly actually, however it only gets data from the specific file in the url. As mentioned, I need to get the most recent one, and changing the url each day is not feasible.

Comment: Start here: https://github.com/features/integrations

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Good Idea. There we go